# is there any way where we can dynamically show the header for each index based on the prop value

Tags: reactjs

i have a table to displayed, for the each row we have nested table, up on clicking the number, the nested table will be expanded. So we are having titles for each nested table header and we are mapping it and displaying.

Now the tricky part is ex: for a nested header title 'a', the particular index row will be having an attribute in props 'show_column' with boolean value. If the column value is false then we need to hide only the particular column from the title.

Is there anyway where we can displaying dynamically for each row.

i was trying to get using the map but got stuck how do i deal with it.

from here the below code, titles is the nested table header values and they are mapped.Row will be mapped from prop values. In the last return we are displaying the table header and table rows.

```
//structure of props would be like as below

heads: {full_name: "Member name", premiumType: "Premium type", class_id: "Class", location_department: "Location", effective_date: "Effective date", …}
**members: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]**
onColumnSort: ƒ ()
onPageChange: ƒ ()
pagination: {records: 550, offset: 0, limit: 10}
sortBy: {columns: {…}, direction: -1}
total: {grand: 8294.77, details: Array(15)}
//and the nested member details of props as below
members: Array(10)
0: {premium_type: "Premium", member_name: "ADDRESS, SPOUSEADD R", class_cd: "0019", location: "", effective_date: "", …}
1: {premium_type: "Premium", member_name: "ALAPAI, ANGLE", class_cd: "0001", location: "", effective_date: "", …}

//members props
  members: Array(10)
0:
class_cd: "0019"
coverage_info: [{…}]
effective_date: ""
location: ""
memb_seq_nr: "1"
member_name: "ADDRESS, SPOUSEADD R"
new_member_added: false
premium_adjustment: false
premium_type: "Premium"
reason: ""
show_plan_column: false
**show_volume_column: false**
total_premium: "8.00"

const titles = [
  { title: a, size: 40 },
  { title: b, size: 20 },
  { title: c, size: 10 },
  { title: d, size: 20 },
  { title: e, size: 10 },
];

const head = titles.map((th, i) => {

  return <th key={i} style={{ width: `${th.size}%` }}><FormattedMessage {...th.title} /></th>;
});

const rows = details.map((item, i) => {

  return <tr key={i}>
    <td>{item.coverage_name}</td>
    <td>{item.volume}</td>
    <td>{item.family_indicator}</td>
    <td>{this.getNumber(item.new_premium)}</td>
    <td>{this.getNumber(item.current_premium)}</td>
  </tr>
})

return <Table className="details"><thead>{head}</thead><tbody>{rows}</tbody></Table>
```

}

Comment: So `show_column` is an object which contains a <title,bool> pair? something like `{'a': true}`?

Comment: yes it's an object but the prop will be like as below
this.props.members : [] has an array of index rows . For example the first the index row will be like this.props.members.[0]. show_column

Comment: Please update your code to show the data structure of the received props.

Comment: updated the code, please find in the comments

Comment: What are you going to use? `show_plan_column` or `show_volume_column`?

Comment: I am going to use show_volume_column it has a boolean value , if the show_volumne_column is false then i need to hide the header {title:a}